# Command which distinguishes between disk I/O and socket I/O

Tags: linux

I would like to measure the amount of I/O per day to /dev/sda.  So I tried,

```
iotop -aoP
```

Here's the output after 1 day:

```
DISK WRITE       COMMAND
   55.06 G      python /usr/bin/xpra start :103
    3.35 G      [btrfs-transacti]
  773.73 M      [btrfs-cleaner]
   25.20 M      python /usr/bin/xpra attach :103
   19.33 M      [kworker/u4:3]
   15.88 M      [kworker/u4:5]
    9.79 M      rsyslogd
```

The problem is that the output does not distinguish between I/O to /dev/sda and I/O to an X11 socket, /tmp/.X11-unix/X103.  For example, the leading entry is only performing I/O to an X11 socket.  I am unsure as to whether the entry [btrfs-transacti] is performing disk I/O or socket I/O.

Is there another tool which can determine the true I/O to a block device?

So far I have tried iotop, iostat, blktrace, /sys/block/sda/stat and /proc/diskstats.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that /dev/sda has a btrfs filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SystemTap (stap)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap).

It is designed for users with more advanced knowledge of the kernel, but I found two pages from the beginner's guide, which seem to accomplish what you want: [I/O Monitoring (By Device)](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/traceio2sect.html#traceio2) and [Summarizing Disk Read/Write Traffic](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/mainsect-disk.html#disktop).

Also if you decide to go with it the [Beginners guide](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/) is pretty good resource.

Answer (score 0):

I initially tried the SystemTap scripts mentioned in Victor Nonov's answer, but they produced similar results to iotop.

I then tried another SystemTap script derived from [this blog post](https://incubaid.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/tracing-block-device-write-request-sizes-in-linux-using-systemtap),

```
#! /usr/bin/env stap
# bio.stp

global writes

probe ioblock.request {
    if(bio_rw_num(rw) == BIO_WRITE){
           writes[devname] <<< size
           printf("Device: %s  bytes_written: %d\n", devname, @sum(writes[devname]))
    }
}

probe end {
    printf("\n")
    foreach([devname] in writes-) {
        printf("Device: %s  bytes_written: %d\n", devname, @sum(writes[devname]))
    }
}
```

but this also yielded results similar to iotop.

Finally I found found a [blog post](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/15/using-systemtap/) from an author of [DTrace](http://dtrace.org) which states that the SystemTap scripts "*are tracing at the Virtual File System (VFS) level, not the disk level* ".  The author includes a DTrace script which claims to measure the number of bytes read at both the VFS and disk levels.  (The script only measures reads, not writes).

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -qs
     2
dtrace:::BEGIN { printf("Tracing... Hit Ctrl-C to end.\n"); }
     4
fbt::fop_read:entry
{    
        @io[execname, "VFS"] = sum(args[1]->uio_resid);
}    
     9
io:::start
/args[0]->b_flags & B_READ/ 
{   
        @io[execname, "disk"] = sum(args[0]->b_bcount);
}   
    15
dtrace:::END
{   
        printf("   %-18s %-8s %12s\n", "EXEC", "LEVEL", "BYTES");
        printa("   %-18s %-8s %@12d\n", @io);
}
```

Unfortunately I ran into trouble compiling DTrace, so I was unable to test this script.